# MySQL-proxy load-balancer issues

Tags: mysql, mysql-proxy

I tried to configure [`mysql-proxy 0.8.2`](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/mysql-proxy/). There are two hosts behind it: `M1` (10.10.10.1) and `M2` (10.10.10.2).

There is a MySQL replication between `M1` and `M2`. `M1` is master, `M2` is slave. All request what type is "write", forwarding to M1 correctly and replicate this record immediately from `M1` to `M2`.

But if request type is "read", the proxy can't forward to `M2`, only to `M1`. I checked these packets with `tcpdump`, and I saw that every packet received on `M1`. The connection from proxy to MySQL servers are working perfectly checking with telnet & MySQL command.

When I shutdown the `M1` server, all request (read/write) sent to another (`M2`) server. After `M1` server is turned off, `M2` is working well. Every record is available.

I don't understand why `mysql-proxy` is not forwarding the read packet to `M2` too, while `M1` is available. What is the problem? Or this is how it should normally run?

This is my config:

```
[mysql-proxy]
daemon = true
user = mysql
proxy-skip-profiling = true
keepalive = true
max-open-files = 2048
event-threads = 50
pid-file = /var/run/mysql-proxy.pid
log-file = /var/log/mysql-proxy.log
log-level = debug
admin-address = 10.10.10.5:4401
admin-username = admin
admin-password = xxxxxxx
proxy-address = 0.0.0.0:3307
proxy-read-only-backend-addresses = 10.10.10.2:3306
proxy-backend-addresses = 10.10.10.1:3306

plugin-dir=/usr/local/lib/mysql-proxy/plugins
plugins=proxy,admin,debug,replicant

LUA_PATH = /usr/lib/mysql-proxy/lua/proxy/?.lua
LUA_CPATH = /usr/lib/mysql-proxy/lua/?.so
admin-lua-script=/opt/mysql-proxy-0.8.2/admin.lua
proxy-lua-script=/usr/local/lib/mysql-proxy/lua/proxy/rw-splitting.lua
proxy-lua-script=/usr/local/lib/mysql-proxy/lua/proxy/balance.lua
proxy-lua-script=/opt/mysql-proxy-0.8.2/riporter.lua
```

Answer (score 2):

There was some issues with that option in the past, but not in the version you're using.

The `--proxy-read-only-backend-addresses` will not cause the proxy to forward the read requests into the backends specified on that option.

For that, you'll need to change a lua script (or write a new one) that reads the read-only-backend-addresses option(s) and define the behaviour your want.

You can read more about this [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/mysql-proxy-configuration.html#option_mysql-proxy_proxy-read-only-backend-addresses).

Hope this gives you some clues for further research.